# Accessing implemented class methods through interface reference without constructor initialization

Tags: java

I have a class `CommonDaoImpl` that implements an interface `CommonDao`. Now i am trying to access the `getRegisterData()` of `CommonDaoImpl` through interface `CommonDao` reference like this

```
public class CommonServiceImpl implements CommonService 
{
    CommonDao commonDao
    public boolean insertRegisterData(CommonBean objCommonBean)  {
        return commonDao.getRegisterData(objCommonBean);
    }
```

but it is not working and thow an NullPointerException

So i slightly change my code and initialize interface reference with the constructor of implemented class CommonDao impl like this

```
public class CommonServiceImpl implements CommonService 
{
    CommonDao commonDao=new CommonDaoImpl();

    public boolean getRegisterData(CommonBean objCommonBean)  {
        return commonDao.insertRegisterData(objCommonBean);
    }
```

But i could not understand why it happens.

Answer (score 3):

In first case

```
CommonDao commonDao
```

it is a member field of your class, which is un initilized which has default value `null` so invoking method on `null` results into `NullPointerException`

while in your second case you are initializing it

```
CommonDao commonDao=new CommonDaoImpl();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why happens what? NullPointerException? It happens, because once you get CommonServiceImpl instantiated, all the fields receives default values. commonDao is a field which default value is null.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you need an instance of `CommonDao` to call the `insertRegisterData`method. The statement `commonDao=new CommonDaoImpl()` creates an instance calling the constructor and assigns it to `commonDao`, so it's not `null` any more.

Answer (score 0):

First commonDao is a **reference** to an **implemented class**

Sicne commonDao is an interface, it **does not implement any methods**

> CommonDao commonDao

commonDao does not referencing an initialized object that implements the interface, so when you call commonDao.insertRegisterData(objCommonBean); comonDao is Null as no memory address is assigned to it currently and it throws a NullException ( See Diagram )

> CommonDao commonDao=new CommonDaoImpl(); < --- This initializes right here

Now commonDao is referencing an initalized object that implements the interface. So when you call commonDao.insertRegisterData(objCommonBean), comonDao interface. commonDao has an address assigned to it which is of an initalized class. So now there's an existing object to reference that has the method.

[image]